# DualMonitor configuration resetting on lock screen after reboot

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, lock-screen

Hollo,
I am not sure I've written correct title, but it's not easy to name problem in few words (especially for non-native English speaker), so be forgiving please.

I've two monitors connected to my computer:

1. in front of me, connected via HDMI, set as primary
2. on the right, connected via DVI-D, set as secondary

I've configured it as I want and it's working until I reboot the PC, then the monitors configuration is resseting, but only on lock screen.
Lock screen appears on 2nd monitor, and the system behaves like the 2nd monitor was on the left not right (mouse behavior). After login the configuration returns to that I've setted.
What curious, after log off  (but without rebooting) Lock Screen appears on correct monitor (1st), and mouse moves over two monitors correctly).

I have:

Graphics: Nvidia Geforce GTX 1070 (one from Gigabyte)
Mobo: ASUS X370 Prime-Pro (I don't know if it's useful)

I've read that in Nvidia drivers there is fixed hardcoded priority of outputs, I don't know if it's true, nor if it can have anything to do with the problem I have.
It's DualBoot and on Windows 10 (1909) lock screen appears to work properly.

Does anyone have similar problem, or know any solution to this?
It's not really important issue, but it's quite annoying...
Thanks in advance.